# SELECT statement with a new column based on a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
month year  id  amount
1     2001  1   345.5
2     2001  1   123.5
3     2001  1   654.5
4     2001  1   542.5
5     2001  1   123.5
6     2001  1   123.5
7     2001  1   654.5
8     2001  1   654.5
9     2001  1   789.3
10    2001  1   654.5
11    2001  1   123.5
12    2001  1   654.5
1     2002  1   123.5
2     2002  1   123.5
3     2002  1   654.5
...
```

and I want to change it with a SELECT statement so it looks like this:

```
month  id  2001   2002   2003 ...
1      1   345.5  123.5
2      1   123.5  123.5
3      1   654.5  654.5
4      1   542.5  ...
5      1   123.5
6      1   123.5
7      1   654.5
8      1   654.5
9      1   789.3
10     1   654.5
11     1   123.5
12     1   654.5
```

I tried a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT
  month, year, id, amount, sum(amount_order) AS YEAR(getdate())-1
FROM
  receipts
WHERE
  id = '1'
  AND year BETWEEN YEAR(getdate())-5 AND YEAR(getdate())-1
GROUP BY
  month, year, id
```

because I wanted to set the table name as the value of the years of past 5 years to past 1 year (here with only the column name of the year before).
Is it even possible to do this with one SELECT statement?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: well sometimes there is no other option than changing it this way and let's pretend
@Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select month, id,
       sum(case when year = 2001 then amount else 0 end) as amount_2001,
       sum(case when year = 2002 then amount else 0 end) as amount_2002,
       . . . 
from t
group by month, id;
```

Comment: Isn't there way to do it more dynamically with pivot ? I'm pretty bad at those syntaxes

Comment: well but does this change the name of the column to 2001/2002 or to your amount_2001. because I want the column name not to be set as a specific name but to a more dynamic one so it is variable with the getdate() function. if you know what I mean. The sum() function is not the problem for this, it is more the naming after the AS.

Comment: @Nihilius Dynamic column names => dynamic SQL => stored procedure.

Comment: is it the one where you DECLARE something? And if it is, can I just DECLARE something right before doing a SELECT ordoes it stay decleared after the statement call? @Akina

Comment: @Cid . . . MySQL doesn't support `pivot` (and I don't like that syntax anyway).  You can make this dynamic if you like by constructing the `sum(case . . . )` expressions and using `prepare`/`execute`.